# Refraction of Sound Waves and Longitudinal Waves

Tags: refraction

How can i prove that sound waves are longitudinal wave?Are there any simple experiment that can be done?

Comment: Related question: [Why are sound waves longitudinal even though they are mechanical energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526748/179151)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that sound waves can travel through fluids shows that it is a longitudinal wave, as fluids cannot support bulk transverse waves due to a lack of a restoring force for bulk shear movement.

Therefore, the fact that one can hear anything from sound that propagates through the air or water shows that sound is a longitudinal wave.